# Priam backup automatic restore

Tags: cassandra, netflix, priam

I have a Cassandra cluster managed by Priam, with 3 nodes. I use ephemeral disks to store my Cassandra data, so when I start 1 node, the Cassandra data dir is empty.

I have Priam properly configured and I can see backups are saved in Amazon S3. Suppose a node goes down and then I start another node. Will Priam know how to automatic restore backup from S3 when the node comes up again? The Cassandra data dir will start empty, so I am assuming Priam would give the new node the same token as the old one and it would restore the data... Right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I have been running standalone Cassandra on EC2, small Cassandra clusters on mesos on EC2, and larger DataStax Enterprise clusters (with Cassandra) on EC2.

I have been using the Priam 3.x branch.

On restore, it calculates the initial_token, updates the cassandra.yaml file, restores the snapshot and incremental backup files, and restarts Cassandra.

According to Priam/Netflix conventions, if you have a 3 node cluster with Cassandra, your nodes should be named some_thing-other-things.  Each node should be a part of an Auto-scaling group called some_thing.  Each node should also use a Security Group named some_thing.

Create a 3 node dev cluster and test your backups and restores with data that you can easily recreate, that you don't care about too much.  Get used to managing the Auto-scaling groups and Priam.  Then, try it on test clusters with data that you care about.