# Installing Priam on Cassandra EC2 cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra, priam

I'm trying to install Priam on our Cassandra cluster for backup purposes.
Following the installation directions (https://github.com/Netflix/Priam/wiki/Setup) I see that an autoscaling group is necessary to deploy Priam. Is it still possible to use Priam even if our servers are not a part of an auto scaling group?

Comment: I've found myself in the same exact place. Did you find an answer back then?

Comment: Ive created an autoscaling group and added my instances there, but later gave up after encountering other problems I dont recall right now. In the end ive backed our instances by using the nodetool snapshot option and uploading it to s3

Comment: Ok I got it, thank you for the quick response. I am searching for tools capable of maintenance stuff and maybe provisioning too but still I have no definitive answer. Are you able to suggest anything?

Comment: Priam is supposed to be a decent answer for these actions, but if it didn't have problems you wouldn't be here now. DevStax's Opcenter will give you a lot of help operating the DB, but without an enterprise license you will have limited capabilities. Since my organization stopped using cassandra I haven't had any new insights in this field, so that's as much as I can give you right now. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to modify the code, the answer is No.

I posted another reply about the Priam/Netflix conventions for instance names, Auto-scaling group names and security group names [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248772/priam-backup-automatic-restore).  I thought the benefits of being able to use Priam outweighed the minor hassle of changing some instance names, security group names, and setting up auto-scaling groups.

Comment: I agree completely, and if the company would choose to keep using cassandra that would be the path I've chose. Thanks for the info, I'll keep it handy in case I'll ever come back this path.